# Create Mail and set focus to this Window

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have VBA code within Excel to create Outlook email. The email does not always get brought to the front.

I added `OApp.ActiveExplorer.Activate`, but this brings the Outlook application forward rather than the new email.

The new email window will have a dynamic window name, making it difficult to locate by code.

```vb
    Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set email= OApp .CreateItem(0)
    With email
        .To = address
        .Subject = subject
        .Display
    End With
    OApp.ActiveExplorer.Activate
```

Comment: `.Display` should do that which already you have.

Comment: In some cases it opens on the task bar flashing, but does not get focus.

Comment: That means you have lost the right to set foreground window. You program must comply with one of 9 rules under remarks - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow.

Comment: Is this the case even though I'm using .display and not SetForegroundWindow

Comment: You are probably doing something else after this code that is conflicting with the `.Display` setting focus. Try it in a test routine where you use ONLY the code you have in this question.

Comment: `SetForegroundWindow` is the only way to do it in Windows. Anything else that that does it is a wrapper around `SetForegroundWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

Call `email.GetInspector.Activate` after calling `Display`.